# In VStudio 2019, VB, .NET-5: for a ClickOnce installed app, how do I locate the application's data directory at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, .net-5, datadirectory

My VStudio is 2019 Community, the application is an old VB Windows/Forms app being brought forward from .Net-3.5-ish to .Net-5.

Under .Net-4.8 or earlier, using the namespace System.Deployment.Application, one could access `ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory` to locate that artificially-generated directory in `\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...` that a 1-click installation would create and populate with data files from the Project Build/Publish.

Under .Net-5, I believe that particular set of functions has been taken out - yet the ClickOnce installer still places Data files there. How do I programmatically locate that directory? The Application Path can be located from `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`, but that doesn't help in locating the data.

This app, an old bit of VB code, has a large number of application data files that need to be installed along with the code. As there are more than 40 of them, we've kept them in their own `\Data` directory, which is included in the Project, is under Git control to keep their versions aligned with their code...

In an uninstalled app, we could keep this \Data directory adjacent to the executable, and find it easily at runtime: but with a ClickOnce installed app, that falls apart. In the Publish configuration, all the data files are identified, with Group=Required, Publish Status=DataFile.

Can I either:

1. Easily configure the 1-click installer to place our \Data directory and its contents into one of the standard \Local\Appname or \Roaming\Appname directories that seem to also get created, but left empty? Those can easily be located at runtime.
2. Easily construct at runtime the path to that obscure data directory that 1-click normally creates and uses for data?

Cheers, and Thanks! Bob

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. There's no `1-click installer`. ClickOnce is the name of a deployment *and* update technology [which hasn't changed that much](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2019). Using `%APPDATA%` has nothing to do with ClickOnce either. All applications, no matter how they're written or deployed, should store non-document data in the `AppData` folders. `Program Files` is read-only to applications and `My Documents` is only meant for documents. Finding those paths never required knowing the app's path

Comment: Finding the special folders is the job of [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0) since 2003 and .NET 1.1. What seems to be missing from .NET (Core) 5 is the ApplicationDeployment class. Adding that class [is tracked in this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/27) and some people have created workarounds. If you have read-only data files though, you can include them in the build as `Content`, not data

Comment: `we could keep this \Data directory adjacent to the executable` no you couldn't, unless the files were read-only. Even when you though you did, you either had to override security settings or Windows silently redirected those files to `APPDATA`. `Program Files` is read-only since Windows 95. In *very old* versions of Windows you could use administrator privileges to overwrite files in `Program Files`. In newer versions, the OS redirects writes to other folders. If you have read-only data though, you can include them as content and deploy them next to the application

Comment: Thanks. (Brain-cramp, meant ClickOnce!) Problem is loss of the ApplicationDeployment class. ClickOnce installs both executables and data in obscurely named folders under AppData\Local\Apps\2.0..., without obvious relation to each other. If ClickOnce could be configured to place the data in a normal AppData\<AppName>\ directory, I'd be happiest.